# Successful sending of data between javascript and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to develop a News Ticker for many websites. I have created at first a dropdown list to select the RSS Feed URL as follow:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="rubChoice">
    <li><a href="#ticker" id="act1" data-item="Sport">Sport</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ticker" id="act2"  data-item="Politique">Politique</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ticker" id="act3"  data-item="International">International</a></li>
    li><a href="#ticker" id="act4"  data-item="Divers">Divers</a></li>
</ul>
```

After that I use jQuery and AJAX to send the URL as an information to a PHP file:

```
    $('#rubChoice').on("click", "a", function(e) {
        var option = e.target.getAttribute('data-item');
        e.preventDefault();
        var url;
        switch (option) {
            case "Sport":
            url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/GalerieArtciles';
            break;
            case "International":
            url = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#';
            break;
            case "Politique":
            url = 'http://www.elkhabar.com/feeds/';
            break;
            default: url = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#';
        }
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php',
      data: { Option : url },
      success: function(data)
      {
        console.log("success!", url);
      }
      });
        });
```

At the PHP side, I would like to get this URL on a function called `getFeed()` :

```
function getFeed() {
if (isset($_SESSION['url'])) {
        $url = $_SESSION['url'];
    } else {
        $url = '';
    }
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
// Other instructions
}
```

But, once I execute the code, I get the following error that mean there is no URL:

```
""<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents() [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: Filename cannot be empty in <b>C:\wamp\www\rss\core\inc\rssnews.inc.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\wamp\www\rss\core\inc\rssnews.inc.php</b> on line <b>46</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\wamp\www\rss\core\inc\rssnews.inc.php</b> on line <b>46</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>C:\wamp\www\rss\core\inc\rssnews.inc.php</b> on line <b>46</b><br />
"[]"
```

Comment: You are doing post method then how you will get data in $_SESSION variable....you need to use $_POST

Comment: "Filename cannot be empty" explains everything.... Did you ever set your url from $_POST into $_SESSION?

Comment: console.log("success!", url);  in JS concat operator is `+` so it will be something like  console.log("success!" + url);

Comment: @Naincy No, I didn't use $_POST. If so how an I use it. the console yes it display the url and a success message

Comment: @Oliver no how can I use it effectively please

Answer (score 1):

The data you post to your PHP page are marked by the "data" field in your Javascript.

So if you want to pass an "url" to your PHP file, replace your line `data: { Option : url },` by `data: { url: url },` in your javascript.

You also have to change `$_SESSION['url']` by `$_POST['url']` because fields submitted by your ajax are sended with POST request

Comment: Ok bro, I try your suggestion but knowing that once I fetch the data I hae to send it back to the html pae so I didn't need to use $_SESSION

Comment: You have replaced $_SESSION['url'] by $_POST['url'] in your Ajax file and it's the same error ? Can you show us the full string error please?

Comment: Sure.
`<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: url in <b>C:\wamp\www\rss\core\inc\rssnews.inc.php</b> on line <b>38</b>
"[]"`

Comment: Did you also change the `data: { Option : url },` by `data: { url: url },` ?

Comment: Yes of course. 
`global $url;
if(isset($_POST['url']))
{
   
 $url = $_POST['url'];
 
}else{
$url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/GalerieArtciles';
}

function getFeed($url) {

 // the value of $url here = the string at the else block, which is not the desire response I've wanted  
    $content = file_get_contents($url);}`

Comment: Why did you add `global $url` ?